# From inner function copy object and get it in outer function

Tags: javascript, object, redis

I want to copy response to `p1`, and then log the value of `p1`.

But `p1` is showing `undefined` or `null`.

The data type is object which is not copying to p1 .

```
display = async () => {
  var p1={};
  client.get('results', (err, results) => {
    console.log('res1',results);
    p1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
  console.log('p1',p1);
}
```

Comment: p1 console undefine or null

Comment: Does `pi` console executes before `res1` console ?